# laravel 5.6 and apache gives 404 for urls

Tags: laravel, apache, apache2.4

I have apache2 server on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and I have Laravel 5.6 project called book_donation in /var/www/html now when I visit localhost the Laravel welcome screens appear no problem but whenever I click on any url it gives:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /book_donation/public/login was not found on this
>   server. Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

and here is .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is my /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
         AllowOverride all
         Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My php version is 7.1 and apache version is 2.4.18, how to solve this?

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite? What url gives you the Laravel welcome screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#configuration), you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the  public directory.

Create a new file  `/etc/apache2/site-available/book_donation.test.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName book_donation.test
    ServerAlias www.book_donation.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/book_donation/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add the following:

```
127.0.1.1   book_donation.test
```

Then run:

```
sudo a2ensite book_donation.test.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then you should be able to visit `book_donation.test` and see your site.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem any new route was not working and gave 404 error. Also check php artisan route:list where new route details showing properly but still it was not working. I also tried following command to make it work

php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear

**Here are my project details**

My DocumentRoot is /var/www/html/project/public. when add new route in web.php, it was nor working and gave 404 error but root route was working fine. Means any new route was working. so I did following changes and it start working.

changed in /etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf

**<Directory /var/www/html/project/public>**

```
**Allowoverride All**
```

and enable url rewrite by running **sudo a2enmod rewrite**

restart apache server by running **sudo systemctl restart apache2**